# Problem with setting time range for GetItemTransaction ebayapi

Tags: html, json, xml, ebay-api

I've been trying to figure out on how to filter the quantity solds for items on ebay using their developer api, however, when I tried filtering data from 'NumberOfDays' into 30 days on the API explorer, it seems to me that the 'quantity sold' did not change when I set it as 1 day. Here's my code on explorer

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetItemTransactionsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>AgAAAA**AQAAAA**aAAAAA**oIjEXQ**nY+sHZ2PrBmdj6wVnY+sEZ2PrA2dj6ACloWlCZaCoA2dj6x9nY+seQ**gCUGAA**AAMAAA**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</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
      <!-- Enter the ItemID  -->
  <ItemID>113223355885</ItemID>
  <NumberOfDays>30</NumberOfDays>
</GetItemTransactionsRequest>
```

Comment: There have been reports of the `NumberOfDays` function returning incorrect results for number of days = 1. Have you had the same results with `NumberOfDays` =2? Consider using date ranges instead btw.. they may be more reliable. E.g. `<CreateTimeFrom> dateTime </CreateTimeFrom>
  <CreateTimeTo> dateTime </CreateTimeTo>` or `<ModTimeFrom> dateTime </ModTimeFrom>
  <ModTimeTo> dateTime </ModTimeTo>`